# How to connect to an HTTPS website via a HTTP Proxy in Node.js

Tags: node.js, http-proxy

I created a local HTTP Proxy server for the test, which works fine for my Firefox and Chrome browsers, however, when I tried the following code, the server simply replied a 400 error.

```js
const http = require("http");

const req = http.request({
    host: "localhost",
    port: 8001,
    method: "CONNECT",
    path: "sfnjs.com:443"
})

req.end();

req.on("error", err => {
    console.log(err);
}).on('connect', (res, socket, head) => {
    // Make a request over an HTTP tunnel
    socket.write('GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
        'Host: sfnjs.com:443\r\n' +
        'Connection: close\r\n' +
        '\r\n');
    socket.on('data', (chunk) => {
        console.log(chunk.toString());
    });
});
```

And the server responded

```html
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: nginx/1.16.1
Date: Mon, 22 Jun 2020 03:00:49 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 255
Connection: close

<html>
<head><title>400 The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
<center>The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port</center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.16.1</center>
</body>
</html>
```

And I wasn't able to use the `https` module to connect the proxy server since the proxy server only accepts HTTP messages. If I trying so, for example:

```js
const https = require("https");

const req = https.request({
    host: "localhost",
    port: 8001,
    method: "CONNECT",
    path: "sfnjs.com:443"
})
```

The proxy server would simply close the connection and throws an error like this:

```
Error: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established
    at connResetException (internal/errors.js:570:14)
    at TLSSocket.onConnectEnd (_tls_wrap.js:1361:19)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:312:28)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:228:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1185:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:81:21) {
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
  path: null,
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 8001,
  localAddress: undefined
}
```

However, if I configure this proxy in Firefox or Chrome and visit the target website, it will work very well, so how does the browser do this and how can I implement it in a Node.js application?

Comment: in `connect` event, you are writing http commands on to an https line. I recommend using a proxy package which will auto do this for you instead of you doing it manually.

Comment: And is there any packages that can do this for me? I'm a bit desperate for that right now.

Answer (score 0):

> And I wasn't able to use the https module to connect the proxy server since the proxy server only accepts HTTP messages

It sounds like you are using the `https` module at the wrong place. You should be using the `http` module to connect to the proxy then the `https` module where you now are using your own custom code: `socket.write('GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n' ...`

```
req.on("error", err => {
    console.log(err);
}).on('connect', (res, socket, head) => {
    // Make a request over an HTTP tunnel
    const req2 = https.request({                   // HTTPS
        host: 'sfnjs.com:443',
        method: 'GET',
        createConnection: () => { return socket }, // tunnel
        path: '/'
    }, res2 => {
        res2.on('data', (chunk) => {
            console.log(chunk.toString());
        });
    });

    req2.end()
});
```

Note that the code above is untested but should illustrate the general idea.

Comment: Sorry there is a small error in your code example and I correct it, but still, by returning the same socket to `createConnection` won't help, the server still responses the same 400 error.

Comment: Are you using the `https` module instead of `http`?